# ENYO -Is there any enyo kind which suggests and autocompletes the domain suffix from a list of predefined email domains

Tags: javascript, enyo

Is there any enyo kind which  suggests and autocompletes the domain suffix from a list of predefined email domains while an user types into the email input field. Entering the first few letters of your domain will display a suggestion. (e.g "@g" for "@gmail.com"). Click, or press tab-key to autocomplete your email domains.  (or tap on the suggestion for mobile users.)

Answer (score 0):

[This Enyo component](http://enyojs.com/gallery/#extras.TypeAheadInput) is very close to what you want. [This jquery autocomplete library](https://github.com/10w042/email-autocomplete) has the logic you want for the domain suffix autocomplete.

Obviously, you'll want to focus on the main logic inside the jquery library and graft that into the Enyo autocomplete kind.

Comment: Its very help full If you tell How to Add this library to input.Can you explain here??

Comment: I will expand on what I wrote above some, but I can't integrate the whole thing.